# DHCP timeout when connecting over managed switch

Tags: linux, arch-linux, network-interface, networkmanager, dhcp

`NetworkManager` DHCP times out when I am connecting via my `Netgear GS108T` managed the switch.

This switch is running on factory settings, and expect it to act as an unmanaged switch for the moment.

I have another unmanaged switch when I connect over the other switch I don't have any DHCP problems.

How can I debug this problem?

For reference my config is

`laptop -> GS108T(Switch) -> router`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many managed switches have a feature to block unauthorized DHCP servers from the network, it's often called DHCP snooping or DHCP filtering. You may be hitting that feature on the switch. I would suggest checking if that feature is enabled, and if your by-interface filtering settings are correctly set.

From the [manual of GS108T and GS110TP](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GS108T_GS110TP_SWA_5Nov10.pdf) (p. 72):

> DHCP Filtering is a useful feature that can be employed as a security
>   measure against unauthorized DHCP servers.  [...]
>   To access the
>   DHCP Filter Configuration page, click **System -> Services -> DHCP
>   Filtering -> Configuration**.